# Select in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Today when my user enter( focus) in a select component he don't open the options. and if I hit enter he open the options.

So I wanna to change this. I wanna that when my user enter in a select component he immediatly open the options to my user select one of thens. and after my user select the option with keyboard arrows and hit Enter I wanna to execute a custom function

Comment: Hey Fabio: can you explain more about what you want to happen? what sort of function do you want to trigger? can it be done using the [Vuetify API's](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) event section?

Comment: I edit the question. tks